# Timer in C# to start an .exe

Tags: c#, timer

I am trying to make a program that will wait for 8 hours and then

if it's 8am or later - run an .exe and close itself (done)

if it's not 8am yet - wait until 8am and then run .exe and close itself

My code:

```
namespace Timer
{
    public partial class Timer : Form
    {
        public Timer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        TimeSpan eight = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
            if (now >= eight)
            {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"Alarm.exe");
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
            // wait until 8am and then:
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"Alarm.exe");
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
            }
```

It's probably very easy, but I am a complete beginner and I can't figure this out myself :/

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Just use the windows task scheduler

Comment: @stuartd: I can't figure out the code to replace this line though: // wait until 8am and then:

Comment: @Dunno123 so you've edited your code.. what's your actual question here? Have you tried setting a breakpoint and debugging the code, if it's not doing what you expect?

Comment: @stuartd: If the timer runs out and it's for example 7am, I would like the program to wait until 8am and then run the .exe and close itself.

Comment: So you want this to run sometimes twice a day with a second to spare? but if its after 12 midnight and before 8am wait. I think you might be a little clearer with the instructions

Comment: @00110001 It's a sort of alarm. I would like to run the program when I go to bed and it would run the Alarm.exe 8 hours later to wake me up, but not earlier than 8am if that makes sense.

Comment: Ahh ok, that makes more sense. So define before 8am, everything is technically before 8am. so i am guessing if the 8 hours falls in the same day its fine ? if it falls on the next day before 8am, wait until 8 am ?

Comment: @00110001 Not sure if I understand your question right, but before 8am is between midnight and 8am I would say. For example if I run this program at 1am, the timer will run out at 9am and start alarm.exe to wake me up. If I go to bed earlier and run this program at 11pm, the timer will run out at 7am, but I would like it to wait until 8am and only then start alarm.exe.

Answer (score -1):

very low tech approach

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var schedule = now.AddHours(8);

if (schedule.TimeOfDay < TimeSpan.FromHours(8))
   schedule = schedule.Date + TimeSpan.FromHours(8);

var timer = new Timer(Callback, null, schedule - now, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan)
```

Comment: Thank you, the last line shows errors though. 'Timer' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments
'Callback' does not exist in the current context
'Timeout' does not exist in the current context